# jQuery Append String vs Object Containing String

Tags: jquery

I understand that both of these will insert html into an element.

What are the differences between these 2 methods though?

String:

```
$("div").append("<h1>Header</h1>");
```

Object:

```
$("div").append($("<h1>Header</h1>"));
```

Is it just that you can do stuff like this?

```
$("div").append($("<h1></h1>").html("Header"));
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it just that you can do stuff like this?

```
$("div").append($("<h1></h1>").html("Header"));
```

**Exactly**

Doing it this way creates for you a jQuery object which can further be manipulated with functions like append, css, addClass

```
$("div").append($("<h1></h1>").html("Header")
                              .addClass("someClass")
                              .css("color", "gree"));
```

Or if you don't want to do further manipulation like this, then by all means pass it just a string, and you'll get the same result.

Comment: I think this answer is outdated - both passing a string or a jQuery object gives the chaining ability for further manipulation. But still, depends on the markup is minor performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there's no practical difference. The function accepts strings because you might want to add a new element which doesn't have a jQuery object yet, and it accepts jQuery objects because you might want to append an existing element or a complex object that doesn't have a string representation.